# Meaninng of "deep pools"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> He often deals with illness, loss and death, but **deep pools** of humor float beneath the surfaces of his films. There is a sequence in "White" (1994) where his hero, a Polish hairdresser, is so desperately homesick in Paris that he arranges to be sent back to Warsaw, curled up inside a suitcase. His friend at the other end watches the airport conveyor belt with horror: The bag is not there, it has been stolen by thieves who break the lock, find only the little man, beat him savagely and throw him on a rubbish heap. Staggering to his feet, he looks around, bloody but triumphant, and cries out, "Home at last!"

Does it mean: his humor are meaningful?

Source: https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/great-movie-three-colors-trilogy-blue-white-red

Comment: It's a weird / pretentious style of writing, where ***deep pools*** doesn't seem like a very appropriate metaphoric usage when coupled with ***float** beneath the surface*. Maybe the writer should have stuck to something more coherent, such as ***hidden depths** of humour* (which would just ***be** beneath the surface*, not "floating"). And I don't think you can make the general assumption that "hidden" humour is necessarily "meaningful" - it depends on context.

Comment: They are not shallow pools of humor. Yep, bad writing as FumbleFingers said.

Answer (score 0):

**Deep pools** means **very large quantities** of humour, in quite a literary-poetic tone of voice, suggesting that humour is in some way a liquid, something like a large body of water.

As commenters have said, it is strange for a pool of water to float underneath something else.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean that alot of humor was hidden in  his work? But because of the word "deep" I think it means "meaningful" am I right?

Comment: It really just means large.  But certainly there is an echo of "deep" in the sense of "very meaningful", especially for these films, which are certainly extraordinary, with many layers of meaning.

Comment: @ViserHashemi, it's the pool that's deep, not the humor in the pool.  Compare *deep pool of humor* (a deep pool, that's filled with humor of unknown quality) to *pool of deep humor* (a pool of unknown quality that's filled with deep humor).